# Can a C structure ever interfere with typecasting?

Tags: c, struct, casting

I have a program that draws lines using line drawing algorithms. I use `gcc 5.2.1` on Xubuntu 15.10 to compile it.

Executing it throws a "Segment violation" fault. Further investigation let me isolate the problem in this MCVE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef unsigned int uint;
typedef unsigned char byte;

typedef struct {
    uint x;
    uint y;
} point;

typedef struct {
    point start;
    point end;
} line;

line new_line(point start, point end) {
    line l;
    l.start = start; l.end = end;
    return l;
}

point new_point(uint x, uint y) {
    point p;
    p.x = x; p.y = y;
    return p;
}

byte points_equal(point p1, point p2) {
    int equal = (p1.x == p2.x && p1.y == p2.y) ? 1 : 0;
    return equal;
}

double line_slope(line l) {
    return (double) (l.end.y - l.start.y) / (l.end.x - l.start.x);
}

/* Naive line drawing algorithm: assumes line in 1st octant */
point * naive(line l) {
    uint numelems = abs( l.end.x - l.start.x );
    double m = line_slope(l);
    point * tbl = calloc(numelems + 1, sizeof *tbl);
    if (tbl == NULL) return NULL;
    int x, nt;
    double b = (double) l.start.y - ((double) l.start.x * m);
    tbl[0] = l.start;
    tbl[numelems] = l.end;
    for (x = l.start.x + 1, nt = 1; nt < numelems; x++, nt++) {
        tbl[nt].x = x;
        tbl[nt].y = (int) ( m*x + b );
    }
    return tbl;
}

/* Main program */
int main() {
    line l = new_line( new_point( -345, -236 ), new_point( -25, -3 ) );
    point *tbl = naive( l );
    if (tbl != NULL) {
        uint n = 0;
        do {
            printf("(%d,%d)\n", tbl[n].x, tbl[n].y);
        } while ( !points_equal( tbl[n++], l.end ) );
        free(tbl);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output of this program is

```
(-345,-236)                                                                                                                                            
(-344,1167693998)                                                                                                                                      
(-343,1167693999)                                                                                                                                      
(-342,1167693999)                                                                                                                                      
(-341,1167694000)                                                                                                                                      
(-340,1167694001)

[ output continues ]

(-30,1167694226)                                                                                                                                       
(-29,1167694227)                                                                                                                                       
(-28,1167694228)                                                                                                                                       
(-27,1167694229)                                                                                                                                       
(-26,1167694229)                                                                                                                                       
(-25,-3)
```

Here comes my question: What does this mean? Would the structure be interfering with the cast? Can something like that actually happen?

*Thanks in advance, and sorry for the unclear, previous statement. May this remade question (and the answer that follows) be a proof of self-learning and willingness to keep Stack Overflow in top notch.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me! The root of the entire problem that would've avoided all the misunderstandings was the type used in both `point.x` and `point.y`:

```
typedef unsigned int uint;

typedef struct {
    uint x;
    uint y;
} point;
```

As both are **unsigned** integers, they "wrap up" once they receive a negative value, just like in the MCVE. This gets corrected by just changing `uint` to `int`.

So keep in mind this when using signed and unsigned numbers!

Comment: Congrats!  clang flagged this indirectly when it noticed you were taking `abs` of two unsigned [was in one of my comments].  Thanks for repost, as I was going to comment on an unrelated question of yours, just to chat on this.  You deleted about 30 secs before I finished a [blistering] comment to _the other_.  I didn't notice early enough.  He was _wrong_.  You had an MCVE, got modded +3, then did pastebin when others asked for it.  I've seen others do pastebin--not a sin, it's a failing of SO that you can't post large code as an attachment like you can on bugzilla

Comment: @CraigEstey Oh, now everything seems logical... That warning indeed indicated it indirectly. As about the original MCVE, it was a conceptual one, made on purpose as the source code was big. When I deleted it, I lost points - signs that I did it wrong (hence the remake). Hopefully it's more understandable for a broader audience (you know, the KISS principle).

Comment: And, I fully expected you would do what you just did after finding the real bug.  Post an answer with the real culprit [and delete the pastbin links].  I said as much in the comment to other [that never got delivered].  Also, I would have sent you a comment to _not_ delete it originally.  You had a tough problem and were far more engaged/responsible that other OP's I've seen.  I've answered questions where there were MCVE comments, and I've been able to fully recode a correct answer (i.e. had MCVE for me).  Sometimes, I've commented back: "has MCVE--see my answer"

Comment: @CraigEstey That's why I got somewhat offended: I'm doing an effort to ask in a way others would understand. By the way, the "solution" of savig the value in an intermediate `int` worked as the number didn't change: just its representation among "almost" compatible types.

Comment: I post/moderate on slashdot.  When I got started, I'd go many rounds with an abusive heckler who just didn't get a simple argument--but wanted one.  Bothered me quite a bit.  Realized: after 2-3 rounds, just walk away--_let_ them think _they_ got the last word [i.e. won].  You'll _never_ convince them [1]: _"2+2=4.  No, it's not.  We learned it in school. Well, I didn't--I don't believe you. Look it up. I don't care--books are a govt plot against me"_.  Seen this in even smart pgmrs. Today, finally had to tell one dude to "move on"--literally. [1] Confirmation bias:  See "C++ fanboi" :-)